# asymmetric hybrid mapping with SLURM

Tags: mpi, openmp, hpc, hybrid, slurm

I want to do an asymmetric hybrid mapping with `slurm`.

My code need to have 3 `mpi tasks`. But, only the `task 1` and `2` need to have more than one cpu. The `mpi task 0` need to have only one cpu.

I use currently this `slurm` configuration:

```
#SBATCH --nodes 3
#SBATCH --ntasks 3
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task 32
```

In this configuration, I allocated 32 cpus for each `mpi task`. But 31 cpus in the node 0 are not used because the `mpi task 0` use only one.

Do you know how I can configure the `slurm` job to do an asymmetric allocation ?

One cpu for the `mpi task 0`, 31 cpus for the `mpi task 1` and 31 cpus for the `mpi task 2`. In this way, I could maximize the use of 2 nodes, without use a 3rd node for just one cpu.

I cannot find in the `slurm` documentation ...

Answer (score 1):

The  17.11 version introduced [Packed jobs](https://slurm.schedmd.com/heterogeneous_jobs.html) so you can specify something like this:

```
#SBATCH --nodes 1 --ntasks 1 --cpus-per-task 1
#SBATCH packjob
#SBATCH --nodes 2 --ntasks 2 --cpus-per-task 32
```

to have one MPI rank with one CPU and two ranks with 32 CPUs.

Comment: Unfortunately the version of slurm is under 17.11..

But, I reached to optimize the running on one node by using the cpu mask option :

   ` #SBATCH --nodes 1` 
   ` #SBATCH --exclusive` 
    `srun --ntasks=3 --cpu_bind=mask_cpu:0x1,0xFFFE,0b1FFFC000 ./mybinary `


When I want to use the same solution for 2 nodes, I obtain an worst computation time! It is could be come from the random selection of the cpus ...

Do you know a solution to select the cpus on the same node for one task ? 

Many thanks @damienfrancois